# Intersection of 2 sets: what is the easiest method for this example?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

(Recall that
$\mathbb{Z} = \{ \ldots ,−2,−1,0,1,2, \ldots \}$ is the integers set,
$\mathbb{Z}^+ = \{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$ is the positive integers set, and
$\mathbb{Z}^- = \{ −1, −2, −3, \ldots \}$ is the negative integers set.)

> Describe each of these sets using the roster method.
> *(That is, describe them by listing their elements, as Z, Z+, and Z− are described above)*
>
> $ ( \{ 1,2,3,4,5 \} \times \{ 6,7,8,9,10 \}) \cap
> (\{ 4,6,8,9,10 \} \times \{ 2,3,5,7,11 \})$

My teacher said there is a faster way to solve the problem rather solve each one by one. Can anyone please explain me how can we do it? I can only do the normal way, which is very long.

Comment: You're new here, so you simply don't know... but I hope you can learn.  First, write *informative* titles that refer to the *content* of your question.  Look how silly and uninformative these example titles are:  "I need help on this problem."  "What's a good way to solve my problem?"  "I've been struggling with a tricky problem:  please help."  And of course yours.  Can you see how vacuous and uninformative they are.  Are the questions about topology?  Long division?  Complex analytic sheaf cohomology?  *What* is it about?  Please fix your title... you'll get more help.

Comment: The roster method was not really clarified since you didn't give us how $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Z^+$, and $\mathbb Z^-$ were described above.

Comment: To solve this problem, think about what element would be in each coordinate of the cartesian product. For an element to be in both sets, it would need the same first coordinate and the same second coordinate. It can easier to see when these are satisfied separately.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1268766/proving-a-times-b-cap-c-times-d-a-cap-c-times-b-cap-d) for a more pared down example that works the similarly to your problem, as well as the proof of the general result about intersections of cartesian products.

Comment: Hi @TrentNguyen, welcome to the forum! I have made some edits to your question. Using MathJax is recommended for writing mathematics, so make sure to click "edit" below your question and have a look at the code there as a first example if you're not familiar with it. It is fairly straightforward if you already know some LaTeX. Also very important: if you receive a satisfactory answer, be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. $\{1,2,3,4,5\} \cap \{4, 6, 8, 9, 10\} = \{4\}$ and $\{6, 7, 8, 9, 10\} \cap \{2, 3, 5, 7, 11\} = \{7\}$, so that the answer is $\{(4, 7)\} = \{4\} \times \{7\}$. Another method involves enumerating two sets of 25 tuples and finding their intersection.